# Two jQuery function didn't work when they are together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

I'm currently coding my portfolio, and I wanted to have my first section which will be an image later, to be a full page scroll, so I used the fullpage.js "plugin" and it worked. Then, I wanted to have my navbar transparent, and when I scroll down to, for example, 600px, it changes the background and text color, and it also worked.

But the problem is that these two javascript/jquery codes didn't work when they are together... I tried everything, like `jQuery.noConflict` etc... but nothing worked, so can anyone help me, please?

Here is my HTML/Javascript code with all the javascrip link for fullpage.js to work in the  :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
//Automatically scroll the first section, then normal scroll
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            scrollOverflow: true,
            normalScrollElements: '.a-text-field'
        });
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
//Change navbar background/text color after scrolling 650px
        $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 650);
        $('a').toggleClass('scrolledlink', $(this).scrollTop() > 650);
    });

</script>
</head>
```

If needed, i'm adding the CSS of the navbar for changing background color and text color :

```
.nav {
font-family: "brandon-grotesque", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 0.3em;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
z-index: 9999999;
transition: 500ms ease;
background: transparent;
}

.nav.scrolled {
font-family: "brandon-grotesque", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
font-size: 12px;
letter-spacing: 0.3em;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background-color: #F3F3F3;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.1);
z-index: 99999;
}

.nav>ul>li>a {
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
transition: 0.30s;
}

.a.scrolledlink {
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
transition: 0.30s;
}
```

I hope someone can help me to find a solution to my problem because it's something I really want to do, and I'm trying it for hours without finding any solution...
Thank's by advance for your response.

Comment: Check your console for errors in your code. Also ensure that `scrolloverflow.min.js` does not rely on jQuery, as you're including it beforehand.

Comment: I checked the console and there is no error in the code. And for the scrolloverflow.min.js, it does not rely on jQuery, I can add jQuery before or after, the fullpage scroll work, but it's the second part of the JS code which didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the second function is not firing is because there is no scroll event taking place.
If you add the option, `scrollBar: true` to your fullpage function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Automatically scroll the first section, then normal scroll
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    scrollOverflow: true,
    normalScrollElements: '.a-text-field',
    scrollBar: true
  });
});
```

It will work.

Comment: Ohh okay! Thank's a lot, I would never thought it was that! It seems to work! ;)

Comment: You are welcome! But the downside of this option is that you will get a scroll bar on the right side of the page.

Comment: oh yeah.. there is no way to hide it ?

Comment: If you hide it the scroll-event will not fire.

Comment: okk, so there are no other possibilities for my code to work?

Comment: If there is no scrollbar jQuery can not detect scrolling.

Comment: edit : i managed to hide it, with a display: none; with it's css class